# how to run unit tests with better-assert and mocha?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, better-assert

I'm trying to run some unit tests with mocha + [better-assert](https://github.com/visionmedia/better-assert) but `better-assert` uses an undefined variable [__stack](https://github.com/visionmedia/better-assert/blob/master/index.js#L25), and so it throws a reference error.

I'm new to the entire node.js stack, and despite some searching I'm not able to find out if this `__stack` variable is something that comes from the v8 runtime, or from node.js, or mocha, or something else. grepping hasn't been fruitful.

using node v0.8.18, mocha 1.8.1, better-assert 0.1.0

where is the `__stack` variable defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TJ Holowaychuk, the author of better-asset, just updated it with a fix for this exact problem. And by "just" I mean within an hour of you posting your question! If you update to the latest version of the module you shouldn't get the error any more.

[Here are the details](https://github.com/visionmedia/better-assert/pull/2) of the change if you are interested.